# Process large amount of data from BigQuery

Tags: php, mysql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am creating some flattened tables in MySQL for reporting purpose and the data source I am using is Google BigQuery. The main purpose of these aggregated tables is to reduce the number of read cycles and to reduce cost as it will run the background job once in a day and then store counts in MySQL. Later, the report code reads from MySQL table and this process continues.

Now the issue I am facing is with the limits. If I fetch the total count from bigquery and run the query in a loo for say 100 records at a time, it will do a number of reads and as it is an aggregate query, it will process all the data in the Bigquery table and there will not be any advantage in terms of the cost as it is doing same multiple querying inside the background job. I am planning to run the query one time and get all the results, but then it is exhausting the PHP memory size as I am getting a very huge data set.

Actually what can I do in this situation ? I have a redis instance and is there any possibility that I can write directly to the redis, without it is processed through PHP ?

Comment: What you are looking for here, do you want to find an optimized way for your query? optimize for costs? reduce data size? How big is the data that doesn't fit in PHP memory?

Comment: obviously I am looking for a way to reduce costs. At one run it will return 5000000 records.

Comment: So you already have pagination in place to parse that data, not sure how you reach the memory limit. How do you get out the data from BQ by pagination or export job to GCS?  Try also to answer my previous questios, you don't give too much details to help you.